# how to dynamically add swt widgets to a composite?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

I'm trying to add widgets like text boxes, buttons to a composite on click of a button.
I've tried , but i could only add these widgets dynamically only up to the size of the composite. My jface dialog is such that, it has a scrolled composite in which it holds a composite. In the main composite i have 3 other composites where i have to achieve this 
functionality, so if i add dynamic widgets to a composite it might expand, but it should not overlap existing composites down to it, rather it should adjust other composites accordingly and also i should be able to dispose those widgets on a button click. Did any one try this dynamic addition and removal of widgets before, I'm new to swt, jface . So, could any one share their experience here, I'm posting the code i've tried.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IDialogConstants;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;


public class DynamicDialog extends Dialog {
    private Text text;
    private Text text_1;
    private Composite composite;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @param parentShell
     */
    public DynamicDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the dialog.
     * @param parent
     */
    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

        composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(new FormLayout());

        scrolledComposite.setContent(composite);
        scrolledComposite.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));


        final Composite composite_1 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
        final FormData fd_composite_1 = new FormData();
        fd_composite_1.top = new FormAttachment(0);
        fd_composite_1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        fd_composite_1.bottom = new FormAttachment(0, 85);
        fd_composite_1.right = new FormAttachment(0, 430);
        composite_1.setLayoutData(fd_composite_1);

        Label label = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        label.setText("1");

        text_1 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
        text_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        text = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        Button btnDelete = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        btnDelete.setText("delete");

        final Composite composite_2 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        final FormData fd_composite_2 = new FormData();
        fd_composite_2.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -91);
        fd_composite_2.top = new FormAttachment(0, 91);
        fd_composite_2.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
        fd_composite_2.left = new FormAttachment(100, -74);
        composite_2.setLayoutData(fd_composite_2);
        new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnAdd = new Button(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        btnAdd.setText("ADD");



        btnAdd.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                Label label2 = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
                label2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
                label2.setText("1");

                Text text_12 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
                text_12.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

                Text text13 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
                text13.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

                Button btnDelete = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
                btnDelete.setText("delete");

                //Point p0 = composite_1.getSize();
                //composite_1.setSize(SWT.DEFAULT,SWT.DEFAULT);
                composite_1.layout();
                //Point p = composite.getSize();
                //composite.setSize(SWT.DEFAULT,SWT.DEFAULT);
                //composite.setSize(p);
               // composite.layout();



            }
        });


        return container;
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the button bar.
     * @param parent
     */
    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL,
                true);
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID,
                IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
    }

    /**
     * Return the initial size of the dialog.
     */
    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
        return new Point(450, 300);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell =  new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    DynamicDialog dd = new DynamicDialog(shell);
    dd.open();

}

}
```

Comment: I'm going to favourite this one, as I have a very similar question myself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204381/swt-shell-resize-depending-on-children

Comment: @GGrec Yeah, this is haunting me for the past week, I'm trying different ways but couldn't get the best out come. So, I'm just trying whether some one could help our cause. Thanks!

Comment: @GGrec I found an example on web which is a bit similar to our problem, [ScrolledComposite Example](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html) try this. Here when ever I add different composites, it is working fine in this example code but when i write a separate code it is not working. One more interesting this is, it is creating everything on a swt shell in the scrolled composite example, where as I'm using jface dialog. Does this have any effect on what we are doing?

Comment: `ScrolledComposite`s are usually a pain. You have to be careful what you're wrapping with the scrolled comp. BUT, if you play long enough with it, you will eventually come to the conclusion that you can actually use a `ScrolledComposite` inside a `Dialog`, and it will scroll too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to set the minimum size of the `ScrolledComposite` each time you add/remove a widget. You will use `setMinSize(Point)` API from `ScrolledComposite`. Also, remember to `layout()` the scrolled composite, and not its children. The laying of children will be done automatically.

The *add* button currently moves along with each newly added component. If you want it to not move, just move it outside the scrolled composite content.

Also, I've cleaned up your code a little bit, I hope you don't mind. :-)

```
public class DynamicDialog extends Dialog 
{
    private int count = 1;

    public DynamicDialog(final Shell parent) 
    {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) 
    {
        final Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

        final Composite composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        scrolledComposite.setContent(composite);
        scrolledComposite.setSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

        final Composite composite_1 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        composite_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

        final Label lblDefault = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        lblDefault.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        lblDefault.setText("Default:");

        final Combo combo = new Combo(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        final Composite composite_2 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
        composite_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

        final Composite composite_3 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_3.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        composite_3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

        final Button btnAdd = new Button(composite_3, SWT.NONE);
        btnAdd.setText("Add");
        btnAdd.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
        {
            @Override public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) 
            {
                final Label label2 = new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
                label2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
                label2.setText( String.valueOf(count++) );

                new Text(composite_2, SWT.BORDER).setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
                new Text(composite_2, SWT.BORDER).setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
                new Button(composite_2, SWT.NONE).setText("Delete");

                // DO THIS:
                scrolledComposite.layout(true, true);
                scrolledComposite.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
                // .. and it will work
            }
        });

        return container;
    }

    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(final Composite parent) 
    {
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
    }

    /**
     * Return the initial size of the dialog.
     */
    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() 
    {
        return new Point(450, 300);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Shell shell = new Shell(new Display());
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        new DynamicDialog(shell).open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful,I don't mind cleaning up my code,i kept it like that because it is a rough estimate. How did I miss that?. Thanks a lot for your solution, and your counter thing solved me one more problem, I thought that when i delete, the composites are not deleted accordingly, but after putting the counter to the labels showed me I'm doing the right thing